# Linux Mint 19 no sound

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I'm having some issues with the sound, when I go to "Audio" settings and try the sound test both of my speakers work but when I try to reproduce something from Mozilla (YT or FB) there isn't any sound.

Those are my alsamixer outputs:
[image]

Comment: You should not post ip or provider information for security reasons. Please consider deleting it. Do you have `pulseaudio` running/installed? You can check by `running ps -C pulseaudio`.

Comment: yes it's installed

Comment: But is it running? Does it return an instance of a process or nothing?

Comment: yes it's running i checked with ps -aux | less searching it by its pid and it was in the output list of the first command

Comment: Does it work on chrome? I think I had a similar issue at some point.

Comment: Yes it works on chrome, how did you solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not entirely sure. And it was on another distro. But there are a few things you can try: reinstall and reload: `sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio` `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`. Then `sudo alsa force-reload`. Apart from that, firefox can't chose where it outputs the sound (As far as I've heard). You should be able to redirect it to the right output with `pavucontrol`. `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`