# After updating Linux Mint I encountered a sound problem; now I’m now getting: unable to launch “cinnamon-session-cinnamon” X session: how to proceed?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I updated Linux Mint on my laptop, and the sound broke. I restarted, but now after the login screen (which displays correctly) it shows a black screen with the message:

> : unable to launch “cinnamon-session-cinnamon” X session - “cinnamon-session-cinnamon” not found; falling back to default session.

I click okay and just get a black screen with a mouse cursor.  I can’t use Ctrl+Alt+t to get a terminal.  Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F2 also do nothing.

Holding the shift key during start up doesn’t open Grub.

Please help me how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!

`Ctrl+Alt+F4` let me access a command line.  I logged in “becky-Inspiron-5379 login” with my username "becky" and password.

Then I simply installed cinnamon `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`.  It seems I inadvertently uninstalled it trying to fix my sound issue.

---

[A comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535130/linux-mint-19-no-sound#comment991932_535130) for [Linux Mint 19 no sound](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535130/linux-mint-19-no-sound) suggests running `sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio`.  I attempted this and...

```
becky@becky-Inspiron-5379:~$ sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alsa-base cinnamon libcanberra-pulse pulseaudio
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 4 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 5,931 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

...removed cinnamon!