# Sound no longer works after updating Linux Mint and I've lost the tray icon: what should I try next?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, intel

My sound no longer works... *what should I try next?*

I recently updated Linux Mint (`uname -r` gives `4.15.0-99-generic`) on my Dell laptop, and afterwards I completely lost audio (using the laptop's built in speakers), along with the tray icon:

> [image: missing speaker icon in tray]

Using the sound buttons on my keyboard, I'm able to increase/decrease the volume and mute sound.

If I play an mp3, the PulseAudio Volume Control `pavucontrol` indicates sound is playing (it wiggles), but there's no sound played:

> [image: PulseAudio Volume Control indicating sound is being played]

I searched the web to follow whatever instructions I could find, but haven't found a solution yet.  I include the results of commands that seem relevant below.

---

#### It's hard to remove pulseaudio

I don't know why, but if I try to remove `pulseaudio` [it'll also remove cinnamon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584133/after-updating-linux-mint-i-encountered-a-sound-problem-now-i-m-now-getting-un), which seems very peculiar.  E.g.:

```
becky@becky-Inspiron-5379:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio
[sudo] password for becky:           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas liburl-dispatcher1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cinnamon indicator-sound libcanberra-pulse pulseaudio
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 4 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 5,837 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I can run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio`, and it reinstalls pulseaudio, but it doesn't seem to achieve anything.

---

#### What my computer says:

`pulseaudio --verbose` returns many error messages:

```
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)utils.c: could not open configuration file /usr/share/alsa/ucm/HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 146/HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 146.conf
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)parser.c: error: could not parse configuration for card HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 146
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)utils.c: could not open configuration file /usr/share/alsa/ucm/HDA Intel PCH/HDA Intel PCH.conf
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)parser.c: error: could not parse configuration for card HDA Intel PCH
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import HDA Intel PCH use case configuration -2
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: UCM not available for card HDA Intel PCH
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:hw:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL front:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to attach to mixer front:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:hw:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Device front:0 doesn't support 44100 Hz, changed to 48000 Hz.
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL front:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to attach to mixer front:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_route.c: Found no matching channel map
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround21:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:surround40:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_route.c: Found no matching channel map
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_route.c: Found no matching channel map
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:surround51:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:surround71:0: Invalid argument
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dca:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dca:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL hdmi:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to attach to mixer hdmi:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL hdmi:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to attach to mixer hdmi:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL hdmi:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to attach to mixer hdmi:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0

[...snip...]

I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 335.99 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing minimal latency to 356.00 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 345.99 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing minimal latency to 366.00 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 355.99 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing minimal latency to 371.52 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Increasing wakeup watermark to 361.50 ms
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] ratelimit.c: 15 events suppressed
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
I: [alsa-source-ALC3253 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
```

`systemctl --user status pulseaudio` returns:

```
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i error` contains:

```
May  3 09:18:15 becky-Inspiron-5379 pulseaudio[1343]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

`inxi -SMA` returns:

```
System:    Host: becky-Inspiron-5379 Kernel: 4.15.0-99-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 5379 v: N/A serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0J3XT1 v: A00 serial: <root required> UEFI [Legacy]: Dell v: 1.10.0 date: 07/19/2018 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-99-generic
```

`lspci -vnn` contains:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1028:0804]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 146
    Memory at d1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

`aplay -l` returns:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3253 Analog [ALC3253 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`dmesg | grep -C1 -E 'ALSA|HDA|sof|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel'` returns:

```
[    0.040832] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.040832] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.040832] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[    0.832689] DMAR: ACPI device "device:6b" under DMAR at fed91000 as 00:15.0
[    0.832705] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.832706] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x915e3000-0x955e3000] (64MB)
[    0.833066] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x19f2297dd97, max_idle_ns: 440795236593 ns
--
[    5.002104] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    5.008203] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.090950] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3253: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.090952] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.090954] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.090955] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.090956] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.090958] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
[    5.090959] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
[    5.090961] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.145473] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
[    5.145517] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
[    5.145556] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
[    5.145591] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
[    5.145627] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
[    5.145667] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
[    5.161995] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
```

`pacmd list-sinks` returns:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 45543 /  69% / -9.48 dB,   front-right: 45543 /  69% / -9.48 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 75.40 ms
    max request: 14 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 75.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 341.33 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3253 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3253 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 146"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3253"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0225,10280804,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

The ALSA report generated via `wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh` is uploaded [here](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=1987c2ac42029fb7bb0d31ee920dd417a41ab9fb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran exactly into the same problem few hours ago. The only way I could solve it, it was by using grub to reboot into the one of the older kernels (such as 4.15.0-96-generic).

It seems this is a bug of this new kernel [4.15.0-99-generic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875985).

I personally decided to remove it by following these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu). In particular, I removed image, kernel and unsigned image associated with 4.15.0-99-generic, I updated the grub and now I am finally back to normal!